# Object with NSmutableArray of objects with nsmutablearray of objects- how to release

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, memory-management

If I have a grandfather object that contains an array of parent objects that contains an array of children objects. Assuming I have released the objects after adding them to the arrays, how do I go about releasing all the objects? Can I just call removeallobjects on the grandfather object? When I do this I get a leak :(

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simply call `release` on the "grandfather" object - it'll then release the "parent" objects, who will release the "children" objects, etc. all the way down. (Or "up" depending on how you look at it.)

In essence when you release an NS(Mutable)Array, it'll release the objects it has pointers to - if those objects happen to be NS(Mutable)Arrays, they'll therefore release the objects they have pointers to...

Comment: That was my understanding to not sure why I'm getting a leak :(

Comment: Make sure that your children are not retaining their parents – that creates a retain cycle.

Comment: Yeah, this means that one or more of the objects in the graph had another, lost retain on it.  That could be a cycle, or it could be just a lost retain.  You can use Instruments' Allocations profile, configured to "Record Reference Counts" to see all the retains/releases that were taken on any object.  It's a great tool!

Comment: @Skeep Just to let you know that @vicvicvic and @ipmcc have posted some additional comments on this answer that may prove very useful. :-)